# Openshift V3: Confusion on Services and Routes

Tags: kubernetes, openshift-origin

I am going through the Openshift V3 documentation and got confused by services and routes details.

The description in [service](https://docs.openshift.org/latest/architecture/infrastructure_components/kubernetes_infrastructure.html#service-proxy) says that:

> Each node also runs a simple network proxy that reflects the services defined in the API on that node. This allows the node to do simple TCP and UDP stream forwarding across a set of back ends.

it can forward TCP/UDP stream while description in [routes](https://docs.openshift.org/latest/architecture/core_concepts/routes.html#routers) says:

> Routers support the following protocols:
>
> HTTP
>
> HTTPS (with SNI)
>
> WebSockets
>
> TLS with SNI

Basically, my requirement is to run an SIP application which runs over UDP and port 5060.

Please help me understand what is meant by service and route in the above context and can I deploy my application on Openshift V3. I found few related questions but those are fairly old.

**EDIT**
Tagged Kubernetes because it is also used within and may be someone from them can help.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Routes are http, HTTPS, or TCP wrapped with TLS.  You can use a service with a "node port", which load balances your app instances over TCP or udp at a high port exposed on each node.

Routes point to services to get their source data, but since routes expect to be able to identify which backend service to route traffic to by looking at the incoming HTTP Host header or TLS SNI info, routes today only support those protocols.

Comment: What about "passthrough" routes? These have little to nothing to do with HTTPS or TLS specifically and are "protocol agnostic", are they not?